# A fixed product preserving problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, ring-theory, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I'm reading a text on linear preservers and I'm having difficulty understaning one proposition.

Let $A$ and $B$ be unital algebras and let $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ be an injective linear map. And let's add another postulate: $c\in A$ and $d\in B$ are such that $\phi(a)\phi(b)=d$ whenever $a,b\in A$ and $ab=c$. The text is trying to figure out some possible relations between fixed points $c$ and $d$. More precisely, it's trying to prove that if $d$ is left (right) invertible, then $c$ is also left (right) invertible.

Here is how the proof goes:

1. $\phi(ann_l(c))\subseteq ann_l(d)$ and $\phi(ann_l(c))\subseteq ann_l(d)$.

$ann_l(x)$ denotes all elements $y$ for which $yx=0$ and $ann_r(x)$ denotes all elements $y$ for which $xy=0$.

2. Since $d$ is left invertible, we have $ann_r(d)=\{0\}$. Then from 1) we know that $\phi(ann_r(c))=\{0\}$. Since $\phi$ is assumed to be injective, we can deduce that $ann_r(c)=\{0\}$.

However, $ann_r(c)=\{0\}$ does not imply $c$ is left invertible in general. So I'm wondering how we can prove the fact that $c$ is left invertible.

Comment: Are you sure you have not overlooked an assumption about $A$? If $\text{ann}_r(c) = \{0\}$, it is possible to *extend* $A$ to include a left inverse of $c$. Either they are referring to this extension, or have made an assumption that all such extensions have been made.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this text and this proposition?  The statement that $\phi(c)$ invertible implies $c$ invertible is clearly false in general.  Consider $A=\mathbb{Z}$, $B=\mathbb{Q}$, $\phi$ the natural inclusion, and $c=2$.

Comment: @AllenBell Thanks for your example. Here is the link to the text: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358260181_Fixed_product_preserving_mappings_on_Banach_algebras . It's proposition 3.1 I'm asking about.  I'm not sure if $\mathbb{Z}$ in your example is an algbra or not. An algebra is a vector space endowed with a multiplication. What is the scalar field of $\mathbb{Z}$ if it is a vector space?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I'm sure I have not overlooked any additional assumption. Here is the link to the text: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358260181_Fixed_product_preserving_mappings_on_Banach_algebras  It's about Proposition 3,1 that I'm asking. I would appreciate it if you could take a glance at it.

Comment: @OSCAR In your statement, you did not define what you meant by an algebra.  As a ring-theorist, an algebra to me is a ring that is also a module over a commutative ring, in a compatible way, as in "Every ring is a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra".  If you mean only to consider algebras over fields, you need to say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement that $c$ must be left invertible is false for arbitrary algebras over fields.  As a counterexample, take $F$ to be any field, $A=F[x]$, $B=F[x,x^{-1}]$, $\phi$ the inclusion map, and $c=d=x$.

The paper you referenced is mostly about Banach algebras, so perhaps the author meant to assume the algebras in Proposition 3.1 had additional properties, such as being Banach algebras.  But Proposition 3.1(2) and (3) are false as stated for general algebras, and your original comment is exactly the reason why the proof is not valid: having zero annihilator does not usually imply invertibility.  If you are really interested, you could write to the author and ask him whether he meant to include additional assumptions.